# Hosting a Linux server on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, gpu, docker

I would like to host a Linux server on my Windows PC. Conditions specific to my scenario are:

- Must be running Windows still (i.e., not dual booting Linux)
- Must have access to GPU
- Must be ssh-able from network

How can I accomplish this? Below are some solutions I have considered, but have not yet had much success with, either due to lack of GPU access or exposing ssh ports to network:

1. Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2)
2. Linux VM
3. Linux container (Docker or Podman)

Any specific guidance for any solution or external resources are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Separate your Dev Environment

I think the best option is one where you can build, destroy, rebuild your dev environment without taking your primary Win PC offline either through dual-boot, or worse damaging the install through changes you make to support  virtualization on top of Windows.  NB: Many things you want to happen in your guests will require changes, including booting with custom parameters/modules (e.g. GPU pass-through, bridged networking).  Not everything ends well :-)

Repurpose some old PC hardware as a separate development environment.  For example a Linux-based bare metal hypervisor can run on as little as 2GB of RAM, plus what you need for your guests so what used to be useless hardware is suddenly very useful.

For simplicity and cost, this is my recommendation to start you getting your feet wet on the cheap.  You could ask 20 people and get 20 opinions, and many of them might be agreeable to me as well.  Just providing a path to follow. My advice is based on my experience and my limited insight into your universe and my sense of a big learning curve that you have ahead with "oops's" and f#d4**#!!!'s and also some 'I hope I backed that up...'

### Hypervisor

Install the FREE **Proxmox Virtual Environment** (Proxmox VE/PVE):
https://www.proxmox.com/en/proxmox-ve

**PVE Guides:** https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/

**PVE How To's:** https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Category:HOWTO

**Install a Linux Guest:**  https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Qemu/KVM_Virtual_Machines

Hope that helps!

### GPU Pass-Through

From Fixed pass-through, to mediated pass-through, to simple device emulation.

Depending on the type(s) of GPU and generation your approach will vary and there is an Internet full of tears from people trying to get it to work in their use case.  I am using mediated pass-through (Intel's GVT-g)  which is natively supported by my onboard GPU (i915).

ArchLinux has a great write-up on GVT-g: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_GVT-g

Comment: I am marking this as the accepted answer, but there is great information in the other answers as well. These answers gave me enough information to realize dual booting linux is preferable for my situation. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Hosting a Linux server on Windows

1 and 3 are special purpose devices and not general purpose virtualizers.

I suggest a professional virtualizing app:  VMware Workstation Pro or Hyper-V.  I have both (two different computers) and I much prefer VMware for its overall flexibility and ease of use.

You can create a Server OS as a VM and set it up with Bridged Networking and then you can access it like a regular server.

Your conditions can basically be met except for the GPU which will be the VMware Hardware providing this. That should be adequate for a server OS.

If you have Windows 11 Pro, newest Hyper-v and desktop computers with multiple GPUs, then Hyper-V may fit your need.

Comment: Thanks John! Would you mind elaborating on the GPU bit? Doesn't VMware support GPU passthrough allowing directing GPU access from server?

Comment: Here is what I am referring to: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere-Bitfusion/3.0/Install-Guide/GUID-2005A8C6-4FDC-46DF-BB6B-989F6E91F3E2.html

Comment: Hyper-V (so far as I know) does not pass through and neither does VMware.  Both provide Video adequate for a server. If you need more advanced Video, you would need something you can customize in this way. QEMU comes to mind but I have no experience with it and from what I have seen not as flexible.

Comment: My interest in GPU access is for ML workloads. Will look into QEMU as well, thanks.

Comment: Hyper-V may fit your need and I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a technical (solution) requirement why you want to host this on your Windows machine?

Comment: @BlindSpots - no not really, just an ease-of-use preference. It's starting to sound like dual booting linux would be far easier...

Comment: You are at the beginning of a journey with lots of twists and turns and lots of side paths. My 2 cents.  If cost is a factor, find some minimal HW, load Proxmox (free edition).  Install Windows VMs, Linux VMs/Containers, Docker.  Play with GPU pass-through, back it up, trash it.  etc.  Leave your Win machine running for what you need it for.

Comment: If you have a use-case (specific need) in mind for your Linux environment let us know and we can zero in on some good advice.

Comment: TBH, my use-case does not absolutely require Windows to stay up and running. I think I can set it up so that I can remotely boot into linux and vice versa, so I am now leaning toward dual booting Linux onto a separate SSD. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you wish to use dual boot you should set up and ask a different question.

Comment: VMWare absolutely supports GPU pass through, the question would be, does your processor support VY-d

Comment: 'does not absolutely require Windows to stay up and running.'  :-D  Does it require Windows to be up and running... at all?  What if you mess up your boot loader messing with Grub or sizing partitions or something?

Comment: I am comfortable enough with linux and grub to do this on my main PC. I always put linux on an entirely separate drive as a precaution :-)

Comment: @John - The answers to this question helped me realize dual booting linux is the right way to go, so it has served its purpose for me. There's enough info on dual booting linux, that no further questions are needed at this time

Answer (score 2):

Only a VM can fulfill all the conditions.

The condition of direct access to a GPU is the most difficult,
called GPU passthrough, is a feature in the newer versions of
VirtualBox and Hyper-V on newer Windows versions.
You will need two GPUs, one for the host.

References:

- [VirtualBox PCI Passthrough](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html)
- [Running GPU passthrough for a virtual desktop with Hyper-V](https://www.techtarget.com/searchvirtualdesktop/tip/Running-GPU-passthrough-for-a-virtual-desktop-with-Hyper-V).